# Сообщение “Wrong username or password” после старта сервера GlassFish

Tags: java, glassfish, eclipse

После запуска сервера либо появляется диалоговое окно, в котором выводится сообщение, что имя пользователя и пароль неверные, либо сервер очень долго (минутами) стартует и отваливается по таймауту. При установке GlassFish плагина никакие пароль и имя не задавались. В логах ошибок вроде нет:

> `май 22, 2012 3:18:02 PM com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger info
> INFO: Successfully launched in 16 msec.`
>
> `INFO: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2 (build 23)`
>
> `INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.46 started in: 63ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8181]
> INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.46 started in: 47ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:4848]
> INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.46 started in: 109ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8080]
> INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.46 started in: 15ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:3700]
> INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.46 started in: 15ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:7676]`
>
> `INFO: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
> INFO: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2 (23) startup time : Felix (2 922ms), startup services(1 297ms), total(4 219ms)`
>
> `INFO: JMX005: JMXStartupService had Started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://myname:8686/jndi/rmi://myname:8686/jmxrmi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итого помогло отключение настроек прокси.

> `Window -> General -> Network Connection -> Active Provider -> Direct`

Answer (score 0):

Перед тем как задать вопрос - попробуйте найти на него ответ сами, с вероятностью 98% что проблемы схожая не у вас первого и уже где-то есть ответ

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102331/glassfish-v3-in-eclipse-shows-wrong-username-or-password-after-starting